# onload event is not working in body tag using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to show the date and time after `onload` event of the `body` tag but it is not working, the JavaScript method is not calling.

Here is my code

```
<script>

    function display_c() {
        var refresh = 1000; // Refresh rate in milli seconds
        mytime = setTimeout('display_ct()', refresh)
    }

    function display_ct() {
        alert();
        var strcount
        var x = new Date()
        document.getElementById('ct').innerHTML = x;
        tt = display_c();
    }

</script>

<body onload="display_ct()">
  <div style="width:300px; float:left;">
       <span id='ct'></span>
  </div>
</body>
```

The `onload` event should work, but `display_ct()` is not calling and the alert never appears.

Comment: Some `;` are missing from your code?

Comment: Does any error appear at your browser's JS console?

Comment: You aren't using jquery, so not sure why you added that tag. But I took your provided code and it ran fine. You are missing the html and head tags though, did you leave that out just for the example?

Comment: Your code actually works. https://jsfiddle.net/s6rodupm/1/

Comment: Consider not using a string for the first argument of `setTimeout`. Your could would work the same if you used `setTimeout(display_ct, refresh)` instead.

Comment: @Haroldo_OK no there is no error in browser console

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be working correctly

```js
function display_c() {
        var refresh = 1000; // Refresh rate in milli seconds
        mytime = setTimeout('display_ct()', refresh);
    }

    function display_ct() {
      
        var strcount;
        var x = new Date();
        document.getElementById('ct').innerHTML = x;
        alert(x);
        tt = display_c();
    }
```

```html
<body onload="display_ct()">
  <div style="width:300px; float:left;">
       <span id='ct'></span>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I believe he just made it runnable.